# como puedo realizar un sql Bulk insert con un archivo plano que no tiene delimitadores, estoy usando un format.fmt file

Tags: sql

Me da este error

> Msg 4824, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Cannot bulk load. Invalid data
>   type for column number 1 in the format file "format.fmt".

Este es el archivo format usado

```
14.0
22
1     sqlchar     0     03     \0     1     ATipo1
2     sqlchar     0     03     \0     2     ATipo2
3     sqlchar     0     02     \0     3     Contry
4     sqlchar     0     03     \0     4     Provin
5     sqlchar     0     02     \0     5     IntID
6     sqlchar     0     35     \0     6     DName
7     sqlchar     0     35     \0     7     Titul
8     sqlchar     0     35     \0     8     Addr1
9     sqlchar     0     35     \0     9     Addr2
10    sqlchar     0     30     \0     10    NCity
11    sqlchar     0     20     \0     11    State
12    sqlchar     0     9      \0     12    USZip
13    sqlchar     0     3      \0     13    Tcode
14    sqlchar     0     3      \0     14    Texch
15    sqlchar     0     4      \0     15    TNumb
16    sqlchar     0     5      \0     16    TExte
17    sqlchar     0     3      \0     17    Acode
18    sqlchar     0     3      \0     18    FAcod
19    sqlchar     0     3      \0     19    Fexch
20    sqlchar     0     4      \0     20    FTnum
21    sqlchar     0     8      \0     21    Rdate
22    sqlchar     0     1      \0     22    Fille
```

Este es parte de la data

```
LLLCCC4400011AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF111111111222333444455555ZXXXVVVWWWWYYYYMMDD 
LLLCCC4400011AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF111111111222333444455555ZXXXVVVWWWWYYYYMMDD 
LLLCCC4400011AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF111111111222333444455555ZXXXVVVWWWWYYYYMMDD 
LLLCCC4400011AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF111111111222333444455555ZXXXVVVWWWWYYYYMMDD
```

Este es el Query usado

```
use dev
go
BULK INSERT III
FROM 'MiData-test.TXT'
 WITH (FORMATFILE='format.fmt');
 GO
```

Aqui esta el query que crea la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE III(
    [ATipo1] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [ATipo2] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [Contry] [nvarchar](02) NULL,
    [Provin] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [IntID] [nvarchar](02) NULL,
    [DName] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [Titul] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [Addr1] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [Addr2][nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [NCity] [nvrchar](30) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [USzip] [nvarchar](09) NULL,
    [TCode] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [Texch] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [Tnumb] [nvarchar](04) NULL,
    [TExte] [nvarchar](05) NULL,
    [ACode] [nvarchar](01) NULL,
    [FAcod] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [Fexch] [nvarchar](03) NULL,
    [Ftnum] [nvarchar](04) NULL,
    [RDate] [nvarchar](08) NULL
    [Filler] [nvarchar](01) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer hay un par de errores con tu archivo de formato. Debes usar dos comillas dobles para especificar una cadena vacía en vez de \0. También debes de usarlas para especificar que se usará la COLLATION por default.

Con el siguiente formato pude cargar los datos sin problema.

```
13.0
22
1     SQLCHAR     0     03     ""     1     ATipo1 ""
2     SQLCHAR     0     03     ""     2     ATipo2 ""
3     SQLCHAR     0     02     ""     3     Contry ""
4     SQLCHAR     0     03     ""     4     Provin ""
5     SQLCHAR     0     02     ""     5     IntID  ""
6     SQLCHAR     0     35     ""     6     DName  ""
7     SQLCHAR     0     35     ""     7     Titul  ""
8     SQLCHAR     0     35     ""     8     Addr1  ""
9     SQLCHAR     0     35     ""     9     Addr2  ""
10    SQLCHAR     0     30     ""     10    NCity  ""
11    SQLCHAR     0     20     ""     11    State  ""
12    SQLCHAR     0     9      ""     12    USZip  ""
13    SQLCHAR     0     3      ""     13    Tcode  ""
14    SQLCHAR     0     3      ""     14    Texch  ""
15    SQLCHAR     0     4      ""     15    TNumb  ""
16    SQLCHAR     0     5      ""     16    TExte  ""
17    SQLCHAR     0     3      ""     17    Acode  ""
18    SQLCHAR     0     3      ""     18    FAcod  ""
19    SQLCHAR     0     3      ""     19    Fexch  ""
20    SQLCHAR     0     4      ""     20    FTnum  ""
21    SQLCHAR     0     8      ""     21    Rdate  ""
22    SQLCHAR     0     1      ""     22    Fille  ""
```

Comment: Gracias Luis Cazares,

Comment: Gracias Luis Cazares, por la aclaración,  
aunque sigue dando error y es como sigue 

"Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Line 3
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Eso es un detalle de compatibilidad con tu tabla. Pon la definición de la tabla para ver cual sería el problema.

Comment: >Bien @Luis Cazares - Aqui envio el crate que se usó para crear la tabla

Comment: Hola @Luis Cazares, añadí el query de la creacion de la Tabla en la pregunta original, dejame saber si es lo que me pediste, por favor..

Comment: `Acode` está definido en la tabla con longitud 1 y en el archivo de formato con longitud 3. Ajusta el adecuado y se debe corregir el error.